Unpopulate input field of certian value when box is unchecked
Context:
Select dropdown for value change(Select Solo to remove one value):
<select id="T" name="unittype" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" required>
    <option value="" hidden>Select one ...</option>
    <option value="Pair">Pair</option>
    <option value="Solo">Solo</option>
    <option value="Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit">Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit</option>
    <option value="Solo to Pair Unit">Solo to Pair Unit</option>
</select>

Adds values to input field:
 $('input:checkbox').change((e) => {
     if ($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
         var curVal = $('#name').val();
         if (curVal) {
             $('#name').val(curVal + ', ' + e.currentTarget.value);
         } else {

             $('#name').val(e.currentTarget.value);
         }
     } else if (!($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked'))) {
         var curVal = $('#name').val().split(',');
         var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== e.currentTarget.value)
         $('#name').val(filteredVal.join(','));
     }
 });

Removes Checkboxes from HTML table:
 const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
 if (checkboxes.length >= 2) {
     checkboxes[1].checked = false;
     
 }

Problem: When the second box that is checked unchecked, the value is still present in input field. I want the value removed. Can some help me modify the code or find a solution to my problem? I tried everything I could think of and it is not working. Note: Names in input field in photo are fictional.
Pictures:
Input field:

Table:

What I tried was Researching online and trying different things that I found and modifying it to where it fits my project. What I expected to happen was second value in input field gets removed. What really happened is that the second value did not get removed

do you get any errors showing up in console?

The issue is if a select another value from dropdown for example "Solo" second checked value is removed from table but not the input field. I added another piece of code.

You need to remove the selected option from the selectdropdown.
I have modified the code to do that. Also I changed the code to stop mixing Vanilla JS and jQuery in the same function.  Now it uses only jQuery code/functions
See full demo below:
  // remove from select box
  $("#T").find("[value='" + selectedVal + "']").remove();



$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedVal);

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var curVal = $('#name').val();

    if (curVal) {
      $('#name').val(curVal + ', ' + selectedVal);
    } else {

      $('#name').val(selectedVal);
    }
  } else {
    var curVal = $('#name').val().split(',');
    var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== selectedVal)
    $('#name').val(filteredVal.join(','));

    // remove from select box
    $("#T").find("[value='" + selectedVal + "']").remove();
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="T" name="unittype" class="form-control" style="width: 50%;" required>
  <option value="" hidden>Select one ...</option>
  <option value="Pair">Pair</option>
  <option value="Solo">Solo</option>
  <option value="Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit">Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit</option>
  <option value="Solo to Pair Unit">Solo to Pair Unit</option>
</select>
<hr/>
<input type="text" id="name" /><br/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Pair">Pair</input><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Solo">Solo</input><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit">Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit</input><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Solo to Pair Unit">Solo to Pair Unit</input><br/>




The issue is if a select another value for example "Solo" second checked value is removed from table but not the input field. I added another piece of code.

can you add a [mre] that replicates the issue? the added piece of code is a select input.  where are the checkboxes you talk about?

The checkboxes are in the table. If Solo is selected in dropdown, then the second value checked in the table is supposed to be removed from the input field.

which table? I am still not clear on what the desired behaviour should be... I added some code to remove the selected option from the dropdown but that seems wrong :)

You need to define a function that will check for Solo, and if so, loop the checkboxes, uncheck those that are after the first and trigger a change event. And of course, set this as a change event for your select:


 $('input:checkbox').change((e) => {
     if ($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
         var curVal = $('#name').val();
         if (curVal) {
             $('#name').val(curVal + ', ' + e.currentTarget.value);
         } else {

             $('#name').val(e.currentTarget.value);
         }
     } else if (!($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked'))) {
         var curVal = $('#name').val().split(',');
         var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== e.currentTarget.value)
         $('#name').val(filteredVal.join(','));
     }
 });
 function handleChange(value) {
     if (value === "Solo") {
         const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
         if (checkboxes.length >= 2) {
             for (let index = 1; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
                 $(checkboxes[index]).prop("checked", false).change();
             }
         }
     }
 }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="T" name="unittype" onchange="handleChange(this.value)" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" required>
    <option value="" hidden>Select one ...</option>
    <option value="Pair">Pair</option>
    <option value="Solo">Solo</option>
    <option value="Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit">Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit</option>
    <option value="Solo to Pair Unit">Solo to Pair Unit</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name">
<br>
<label for="A"><input type="checkbox" id="A" value="A">A</label>
<br>
<label for="B"><input type="checkbox" id="B" value="B">B</label>
<br>
<label for="C"><input type="checkbox" id="C" value="C">C</label>
<br>
<label for="D"><input type="checkbox" id="D" value="D">D</label>



Another snippet where the behavior is triggered for all changes:


$('input:checkbox').change((e) => {
     if ($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
         var curVal = $('#name').val();
         if (curVal) {
             $('#name').val(curVal + ', ' + e.currentTarget.value);
         } else {

             $('#name').val(e.currentTarget.value);
         }
     } else if (!($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked'))) {
         var curVal = $('#name').val().split(',');
         var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== e.currentTarget.value)
         $('#name').val(filteredVal.join(','));
     }
 });
 function handleChange(value) {
         const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
         if (checkboxes.length >= 2) {
             for (let index = 1; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
                 $(checkboxes[index]).prop("checked", false).change();
             }
         }
 }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="T" name="unittype" onchange="handleChange(this.value)" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" required>
    <option value="" hidden>Select one ...</option>
    <option value="Pair">Pair</option>
    <option value="Solo">Solo</option>
    <option value="Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit">Pair Unit acting like a Solo Unit</option>
    <option value="Solo to Pair Unit">Solo to Pair Unit</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name">
<br>
<label for="A"><input type="checkbox" id="A" value="A">A</label>
<br>
<label for="B"><input type="checkbox" id="B" value="B">B</label>
<br>
<label for="C"><input type="checkbox" id="C" value="C">C</label>
<br>
<label for="D"><input type="checkbox" id="D" value="D">D</label>




this only works if the selected/checked item is solo :(

@blurfus that was on purpose, because my understanding was that you wanted to trigger the behavior only in that case. Lemme add another snippet where this will be triggered in other cases too. Also, should the checkbox labels match the options?

I am not the OP - it was just an observation.  Based on the OPs wording, it seems it should not be limited to only 'Solo' - it was just used as an example

@blurfus sorry, I presumed you were the asker. If you check or uncheck a checkbox, then you will see the content of the input refreshed accordingly. So the question was how the input can be refreshed upon selecting a given option (Solo means "single") that means that a single element should be chosen. In this case the op wants to remove the labels from the second onwards from the input as well as unchecking them. Your snippet does not refresh the input's content upon the choosing of Solo

I know what solo means but thanks :)
What would be the behaviour is the selected option is Solo to Pair Unit? - I think your code always selects the first checkbox selected (no matter what is checked or selected in the dropdown) and deselects the rest of them...

@blurfus yes, indeed, that's the behavior. I was not sure which to select, I was only sure that exactly one needs to be selected and only that needs to be part of the input's value.
